# How to install Windows Media Encoder 9 series

Tags: encoding, media

I want to install Windows Media Encoder 9 series on Ubuntu, but wine is not running the `.exe` file.

A popup says,

> This version of Windows Media Encoder can only be installed on a computer running Microsoft Windows XP

I also used this command but it didn't work:

```
sudo apt-get install wmencoder
```

How can I do it?

Comment: A pop up appears with this message "This version of window media encoder can only be installed on a computer running Microsoft windows xp".

Comment: What are you using the software for? Perhaps there is a native Ubuntu program you can use for the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to tell you but WME9 does not yet work on Wine. You can see the information about it here: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=14306&iTestingId=42161

I would have recommended changing the Operating System to Windows XP:

[image]

But this would only end with another error about not being able to install it. In the comments mentioned in winehq inside the bug reports they say about making sure you have all DirectX components installed. Already did that with no luck. The problems still appears to be with DirectShow and DirectSound.

Even tried to install the Encoder Pro 4 which is the new version to see if that one worked. Installing Silverlight worked. Installing the Encoder Pro 4 did not.

So for the moment there is no way to install this encoders aside from installing Virtualbox and installing them in a virtual windows system.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you either need to tell Wine to emulate a Windows XP environment, or deal with having to get Windows.  This is a common occurrence among my friends, where they install windows software on linux, but then can't use it because of problems with it not being XP.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Media Encoder 9 was developed for Windows, not Linux. I tried to install the application using Wine, and the installer ran, but the main program would not run. I also tried looking for `cscript.exe`, the script that was supposed to come with the program to encode things via command line, but I could not find it.

Unless you can install the program, and find `cscript.exe` and use that (and you might run into trouble running it even if you do find it), you'll have to stick to Linux alternatives such as FFmpeg.